# strange StyleSheet error with react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, stylesheet

I have an javascript file that contains 2 classes. For both classes I have separate StyleSheets. As shown below:

```
export class PageOne extends Component {
   render(){
      return(
        <View style={pageOne.container}>
        ...
        </View>
   )
}

const pageOne = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#FFDD33',
      flex: 1,
      width: '100%',
      flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    ...
});

export class PageTwo extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
        <View style={pageTwo.container}>
        ...
        </View>
      )
   }

const pageTwo = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     *Error ^*
   backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
   flex: 1,
   width: '100%',
 },
 ...
});
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFqRf.png)

Comment: Can you paste the output of the error as text? The image cropped out some important information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed a `}` closing your PageOne and PageTwo class components.

Try this:

```
export class PageOne extends Component {
   render() {
        return(
            <View style={pageOne.container}>
            ...
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const pageOne = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#FFDD33',
      flex: 1,
      width: '100%',
      flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    ...
});

export class PageTwo extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={pageTwo.container}>
                ...
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const pageTwo = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     *Error ^*
   backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
   flex: 1,
   width: '100%',
 },
 ...
});
```